# adding a description to view accordion

Tags: views, navigation

I am using a view with the format Views Accordion.
So far, I have a View like so:

> award1
>      -person1
>     -person2
>   ...
>   award_n
>     -person_n
>     -person_n+1

Where award is the "header" or "trigger" of the accordion action.
This works just as intended. I'm trying to extend this further to look something like:

> award1
>     This is a description of award1. I'm summarizing award1 here.
>     -person1
>     -person2
>   ...
>   award_n
>     This is a description of award_n. I'm summarizing award_n here.
>     -person_n
>     -person_n+1

The problem is when i use views accordion with a description like above i get the not so desired result:

> award1
>     This is a description of award1. I'm summarizing award1 here.
>     -person1
>     This is a description of award1. I'm summarizing award1 here.
>     -person2

Where the description and the person are overlapping and/or pushing the content out of the accordion effect. I've thought about using Javascript to insert the description after the award div, but i feel like that is a hacky approach to the solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably a dirty workaround, but can't you just use the description as "person1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Volker's comment, I created a new person with the name "award_name description" and assigned the proper award to the person just created.

In Views Accordion settings I checked the box "Add views row classes
Add the default row classes like views-row-1 to the output."

Style the views-row-1 class to make the description pretty.

I have the setting "Add striping (odd/even), first/last row classes", so i had to edit the CSS to swap even and odd so the description has a white background.

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem!